# Column name already exist csv C# application

Tags: c#

I have `Datagrid` view where i need to fetch data from csv file

CSV file image : 
[image]

Showing error

> Column name already exist

Please can any one write the working code for me

Complete Code :

```
Form form1 = new Form();
DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();
dataGridView1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

//Read the data from text file
string[] textData = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\vikas\\Desktop\\fetch.csv");
string[] headers = textData[0].Split(',');

//Create and populate DataTable
DataTable dataTable1 = new DataTable();
foreach (string header in headers)
dataTable1.Columns.Add(header, typeof(string), null);
for (int i = 1; i < textData.Length; i++)
dataTable1.Rows.Add(textData[i].Split(','));

//Set the DataSource of DataGridView to the DataTable
dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable1;
form1.Controls.Add(dataGridView1);
form1.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Columns A, and B are the same.

Comment: Does your CSV have an Header (the first row defines the Fields/Columns names)? If not, then add them. Or create first the DataTable's Columns in code. You could just add a progressive `Column1`, `Column2` etc..

Comment: Looks like your CSV doesn't have a headers row. Can you edit your post to include what your CSV file looks like in Notepad?

Answer (score 3):

Columns in a `DataTable` cannot have the same name.
You're getting the names of your columns from the first line in your file.
Therefore, you're trying to create 4 columns named "vr", "vr", "localhost", "1521", and "orcl.168.0.7".

You can't have both column 1 and column 2 (A and B from your screenshot) be named "vr".
You need to add an actual header row with unique values in your CSV file, change one of those values (although they seem like data..), or give them explicit names that aren't sourced from the file itself.